# Why are some images not displaying after migration to localhost?

Tags: media, migrations

I just moved a site from a production environment to an ubuntu based localhost set up and some of the images aren't displaying and are popping up in the console as 404 errors.

The files are present on the localhost set up, and they have the same permissions as the images that do show up. I think this means that the files are corrupted. So,

1. How do I test/fix this?
2. How can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm my case the files were getting corrupted durring transfer via ftp. Archiving the files first and then transferring the archive solved the problem.